# Can anyone help me fixing this vs code black screen? I have tried everything

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I am getting black screen when I launch vs code (windows 10). Got help from some of the answers so I added --disable-gpu at the end of target section in vs code properties but it didn't work. So I uninstalled and installed it again in different disk and done the same changes but still screen is black. Can someone tell some other way to solve this issue?

Comment: and deleting `%appdata%\Code\User` directory?